# Vuetify V-flex full only half of card

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My v-flex it is not respecting my orders and only half of element it was rendered. see the print:

[Print from my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgJKM.png)

Here is my script:

```
<v-card-title primary-title>
              <div>
                <p class="subheading grey--text">My title</p>
                <h3 class="headline my-4">my sub title</h3>
                <div>
                  <v-container fluid>
                    <v-card flat v-for="ticket in tickets" :key="ticket.id">
                      <v-layout row wrap :class="`pa-2 ticket ${ticket.status.id}`">
                        <v-flex xs3>
                          <div class="caption grey--text">#ID</div>
                          <div>{{ticket.id}}</div>
                        </v-flex>
                        <v-flex xs3>
                          <div class="caption grey--text">Assunto</div>
                          <div>{{ticket.subject}}</div>
                        </v-flex>
                        <v-flex xs3>
                          <div class="caption grey--text">Criado em</div>
                          <div>{{ticket.created_on}}</div>
                        </v-flex>
                        <v-flex xs3>
                          <div class="right">
                            <v-chip
                              small
                              :class="`${ticket.status.id} white--text caption my-2`"
                            >{{ticket.status.name}}</v-chip>
                          </div>
                        </v-flex>
                      </v-layout>
                    </v-card>
                  </v-container>
                </div>
              </div>
            </v-card-title>
```

Someone has any ideas?

Tks.

Comment: change `<v-layout row weap...` to `<v-layout row wrap...`

Comment: @Andrew1325 it was really wrong. i fixed it as you said. but didnt work yet. Any another ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a full width flex box above the v-card on line 7:

```
 <v-flex xs12>
   <v-card flat v-for="ticket in tickets" :key="ticket.id">  
     ...
```

EDIT: My mistake... after taking another look you can change the div on line 2 to a v-flex, which will give you the results like in this codepen: https://codepen.io/retrograde/pen/ZNYJRq?editors=0001    Note that I removed the code added by my original answer.

Comment: Did you say add the xs12 to the flex tag? i did it. but isnt work yet;  Any another ideas?